# knockout components with requirejs not loading

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, requirejs

I am using knockoutjs components with requirejs AMD loader and for some reason the components won't load. no errors, and the scripts are all showing to load to the page, but nothing is displaying.  why doesn't it display the main_ribbon.html on index.html from the main_ribbon.js viewmodel

index.html

```
<mainRibbon></mainRibbon>
```

_layout.html

```
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/boot/require.config.js")></script>
<script type="text/javascript" data-main=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/boot/init.js") src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/require.js") ></script>
```

require.config.js

```
var require = {

    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date().getTime())
    , waitSeconds: 200
    , paths: {
        waitSeconds: 200,
        "bootstrap": "/Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap",
        "jquery":"/Scripts/jquery/jquery-3.1.1",
        "knockout": "/Scripts/knockout/knockout-3.4.0",
        "text": "/Scripts/text.js",
        "domReady": "/Scripts/domReady",
        "bindinghandlers":"/Scripts/knockout/bindinghandlers",
        "postbox":"/Scripts/knockout/knockout-postbox",
        "kendo":"/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.all.min",
        "moment":"/Scripts/moment/moment",
        "toastr":"/Scripts/toastr/toastr"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps:["jquery"]
        },
        "bindinghandlers": {
            deps:["jquery","knockout"]
        },
        "kendo": {
            deps:["jquery"]
        },
        "postbox": {
            deps:["jquery","knockout"]
        }

    }

}
```

init.js

```
require(['jquery', 'knockout', '/Scripts/app/appViewModel.js', 'postbox', 'bootstrap', 'bindinghandlers','domReady!','/Scripts/app/components/main_filter/main_ribbon.js'], function ($, ko, appViewModel, postbox) {


    ko.components.register('mainRibbon', { require: '/Scripts/app/components/main_filter/main_ribbon' });


    ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
})
```

main_ribbon.js

```
define(['knockout', '/Scripts/text.js!./main_ribbon.html', 'kendo', '/Scripts/app/models/m_main_ribbon.js', '/Scripts/app/constants/cont.js', 'postbox'],function (ko, main_ribbon, k, model, cont) {

        function rvm() {
            var self = this;

            self.test = ko.observable("test");

            model.data();

            console.log("myloading");

            cont.xhr_get("/RibbonFilter/MainFilter").done(function (allData) {


            });

        }// end vm
        return { viewModel: rvm, template: main_ribbon };
    });
```

main_ribbon.html

```
<label>this page should load</label>
    <label data-bind="text: test"></label>
```

Comment: Just a hunch but can you try renaming your component to `main-ribbon`? Use it as `main-ribbon` and register it as `main-ribbon` also. I tried using camel case but it doesn't work, camelCasing is not a valid custom element name.

Comment: Adrian I just found the same thing, had no idea I couldn't use camel case. that solves it!

Comment: Cool, I didn't know it also before this one.